# gem namespaces within rails class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I'm brand new to rails (and ruby) and having a a lot of trouble with accessing different namespaces. Specifically, I can't access the namespace of the [flickraw](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/flickraw/0.9.8) gem from within a controller class:

```
class ImageSourcesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        list   = flickr.photos.getRecent
        ...
    end
end
```

Calling this method, I get the response:

```
undefined local variable or method `flickr' for #<ImageSourcesController:0x00000005006658>
```

I am using bundler, which I thought ensured that the methods of all gems in the gemfile are required by rails.

EDIT: I'm stupid, turns out I just needed to reset the server!

Comment: Check this example: https://railsfornovice.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/flickr-with-rails3/

Comment: I did see that example, but when I require 'flickraw' I get the error: "cannot load such file -- flickraw"

I thought that bundler was meant to make all the gems accessible? Ie require is not necessary?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the [original documentation](https://github.com/hanklords/flickraw)?

Comment: You are right @user1618840, rails automatically require all gems files for you, bu I was curious if you tried that tutorial since I didn't used that gem. I've created a test application in Rails 4.1.10 and ruby 2.2.1 and everything works. Did you include the gem in Gemfile right?

Comment: @radubogdan yep definitely included the gem, and checked that it was installed with bundle show

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to create an initializer for flickraw:

```
# config/initializers/flickraw.rb
FlickRaw.api_key= ENV['FLICKR_API_KEY']
FlickRaw.shared_secret= ENV['FLICKR_API_SECRET']
```

If you are creating a open source app you may want to use ENV variables to store your API key and shared secret. The [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem is a really nice tool for that.

You also seem to be confused about namespaces in Ruby. Ruby doesn't actually have namespaces in the same way as for example PHP which has a special keyword and namespace accessors.

Ruby has modules which act as both namespaces (grouping classes, constants etc.) and traits. `Foo::Bar.create()` is an example of accessing a class method on a "namespaced" class.

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def create
    end
  end
end
```

Your flickraw example is simply accessing nested properties (which does'nt really have anything to do with namespaces):

```
 flickr.photos.getRecent
```

Your taking the object `flickr` (which flickraw creates when we require flickraw) and sending it the message `photos` which returns a `FlickRaw::Flickr::Photos` instance.

We then send the message `getRecent` to `flickr.photos`

Comment: Fair enough, I guess then my question is why hasn't flickraw created the flickr object for my app?

Comment: Make sure `config/application.rb` includes the line `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`. Check if you by any chance have added flickraw into a group such as `group :test` in your gemfile.

Comment: Also make sure to restart your Rails server - it may not pickup on new gems being installed.

Comment: haha you got it spot on with restarting the server. Thanks for your help